# javascript create case insensitive regex from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to do validations by matching inputs to regexes in a case insensitive way. The regex comes down from service as a string on an object. I might get something like:

```
{regex:"ane"}
```

I can do the following:

```
var rx = new RegExp(object.regex);  /*The regex is now: /ane/*/
"plane".match(rx);
```

However, I what I really want to do is the following:

```
var rxInsensitive = new RegExp(/ane/i);  /*The regex is now: /ane/i */
"plANE".match(rx);
```

I am having problems converting the string to this form however. When I do the following:

```
var rxInsensitive = newRegExp(object.regex + "/i");
```

I end up getting the regex `/ane/i/` instead of `/ane/i`. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var re = new RegExp("pattern", "flags");
```

so it would be

```
var rx = new RegExp(object.regex,"i");
```

[See MDN for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Wow, just what I needed, thank you for the quick response. I will accept when it becomes available.

Comment: I wonder how can we do the same using regex literal notation instead of constructor notation e.g. matching or 2 label with case in-sensitiveness `(label1|label2)` ?